# How to take the value from selectedOption And display it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just want to show you the value it received

```
    handleChange = (selectedOption, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        selectedOption
    });
    console.log(selectedOption);
}

render() {
    let options = [];
    if (this.state.cityName && this.state.cityName.length > 0) {
        options = this.state.cityName.map((cityName) => {
            return {
                value: cityName.AdministrativeArea.LocalizedName,
                label: cityName.AdministrativeArea.LocalizedName,
                id: cityName.Key
            };
        })
    }
    return (
        <div className="container">

            <h1 htmlFor="Search">Search</h1>
            <Select
                name="htmlForm-field-name"
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={(e) => this.handleChange}
                defaultValue='Jerusalem'
                options={options}
            />
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.value}
                </ul>
```

How to do it with selectedOption

**And another question is how do I do defaultValue within the API?**

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this.state.value` but updating `this.state.selectedOption`. Both of them must be the same. I think you are using Material UI Select so I do the same:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Select, MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core';

class Test extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: ""
  };

  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({
      selectedOption
    });
    console.log(selectedOption);
  };

  render() {
    let options = [];
    if (this.state.cityName && this.state.cityName.length > 0) {
      options = this.state.cityName.map(cityName => {
        return {
          value: cityName.AdministrativeArea.LocalizedName,
          label: cityName.AdministrativeArea.LocalizedName,
          id: cityName.Key
        };
      });
    }
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1 htmlFor="Search">Search</h1>
        <Select
          name="htmlForm-field-name"
          value={selectedOption}
          onChange={e => this.handleChange(e.target.value)}
        >
          {options.map(o => <MenuItem value={o.value}>{o.label}</MenuItem>)}
        </Select>
        <div>
          <ul>{selectedOption}</ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: He gives me >>>>TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
onChange

Comment: Updated the answer. Now you can test it.

Answer (score 0):

Working example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

class App extends Component {
  handleChange = el => {
    console.log(el.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Select
          style={{ width: 100 }}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          options={[
            { value: "green", label: "Green", color: "#36B37E" },
            { value: "forest", label: "Forest", color: "#00875A" },
            { value: "slate", label: "Slate", color: "#253858" },
            { value: "silver", label: "Silver", color: "#666666" }
          ]}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

See example:

[image: Edit select]

Comment: but I do not import from material iam import  from import Select from 'react-select';

Comment: I've done it already. What I want to do is see it in div from where I see it in select